# Push a widget to the end of the screen - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a screen and it has 2 (top-level) widgets, a Card() and a Button()

The Card() has to be placed at the center of the screen and the button at the end.

Now, I've centered the MainAxisAlignment() of the Column() where both the above widgets are parts of its children[].

Now, this obviously puts both the widgets at the center of the screen and I've tried the following approaches to put the Button() at the end.

1. Use Expanded() for the Card(). But this alters the height of the Card() and assigns the remaining space to it and trumps the height that I've specified to it.
2. Use SizedBox() between the two widgets. But this push both the widgets in the opposite direction.
3. Use Align() around the Button(). But assigning Alignment.bottomCenter() to its alignment makes no difference.
4. Use Expanded() for the Button(). But this produces the same visual result as #1, only thing is now the Button() is taking the entire space.
5. Use Spacer() between both the widgets. But this pushes both the widgets to the extreme ends.

Here's my code (without any of the above approaches implemented)

```
Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 30,
                      horizontal: 20,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Your Phone!',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 32,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        const Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Phone Number'),
                            TextField(),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                            'A 4 digit OTP will be sent via SMS to verify your mobile number!'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('Continue'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

What should I do to achieve the desired UI?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Spacer()` widget at the middle of the two widget?

Comment: Ohh, yes!! I forgot to mention that. That takes the two widgets at both the extremes.

Comment: no. I've added this option in my original question now!!

Comment: If it pushes to both ends, try to add a new `Spacer` at the top of the card. Then to control them more, try to play with the `flex` property.

Comment: One workaround that I've found is to add SizedBox() around the Card(). But I think that was not the best solution!!

Comment: Another option is to get the available constraint provided by this current page through `LayoutBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filling the gaps with `Spacer`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _CardView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Spacer(),
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 30,
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Your Phone!',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 32,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                    ),
                    const Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('Phone Number'),
                        TextField(),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                        'A 4 digit OTP will be sent via SMS to verify your mobile number!'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Continue'),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put an Spacer before the card and an Expanded after it so it will be symmetrical, then you can position the button inside the second expanded as you want with Align.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      const Spacer(),
      SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 30,
              horizontal: 20,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Your Phone!',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                ),
                const Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Phone Number'),
                    TextField(),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                ),
                const Text(
                    'A 4 digit OTP will be sent via SMS to verify your mobile number!'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Continue'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tru to Use Expanded Widget like below Code:

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 30,
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Your Phone!',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 32,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                    ),
                    const Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('Phone Number'),
                        TextField(),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                        'A 4 digit OTP will be sent via SMS to verify your mobile number!'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('Continue'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: nope!! it streches the card top to bottom!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple you need to the add two Spacer widgets surrounding the card, see the below code:

```
Widget _cardButton2() {
return Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      const Spacer(),
      SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 30,
              horizontal: 20,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Your Phone!',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                ),
                const Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Phone Number'),
                    TextField(),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                ),
                const Text(
                    'A 4 digit OTP will be sent via SMS to verify your mobile number!'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('Continue'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X99Dx.png)